# Why Travis CI fails at testing my Laravel web route?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, travis-ci

On my local machine all my phpunit tests passed successfully. But when the tests run on Travis CI, the one testing my Laravel web route fails.

Here is my route definition:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*')->name('landing');
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * return the main view
 * @return view
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('landing');
}
```

(My Laravel view is named `landing.blade.php`)

And here is my test:

```
/**
 * test return main web view
 *
 * @test
 */
public function testLandingViewIsReturned()
{
    $response = $this->get(route('landing', ['any' => '']));

    $response->assertSuccessful()
        ->assertViewIs('landing');
}
```

The Travis CI log:

```
1) Tests\Unit\RouteTest::testLandingViewIsReturned
Response status code [500] is not a successful status code.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Again, this test passes on my local dev env.
What's wrong with Travis?

Comment: We can't tell you. A 500 http status code means *something* went wrong in your code. You will have to check your logs to see some detailed error messages. Without it it's impossible to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @DirkScholten Thanks for pointing me out the necessity to check logs, I was totally focused on the assertion fail and my code.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: my `mix-manifest.json` was missing during Travis build because I forgot to `npm run dev` in my .travis.yml configuration file.

The exception wasn't throw on my local env because I build assets every day.